Unable to generate build in anchor , want to know the stable version of solana-sdk and solana-client compaitable
what should be the version of crates, since I am getting error of async-trait all time
    error: failed to select a version for the requirement `async-trait = "^0.1.77"`

The version details which would help me are:

solana-client,
solana-sdk,
solana-program,
solana-program-test,

This is my cargo.toml file looks like right now and is generating build uptill now but further I add dependencies It causes me error in build
[package]
name = "abc"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]  
name = "abc"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.29.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = "0.29.0"
solana-program = { version = "1.18.9", optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
spl-token = { version = "^3.5.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
num = "0.4.0"
async-trait = "0.1.52"
solana-sdk = "1.18.9"
spl-associated-token-account = "1.0.3"


I think you'll need to upgrade a few crates if you want to use solana 1.18. Check out the current Cargo.toml for anchor v0.30.1: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/spl/Cargo.toml -- it might work if you just copy all of those
